# jQuery each() giving me two different results with nested objects

Tags: jquery, each, javascript-objects

I'm trying to use the code below and it works the way I want it by alerting with honda, toyota, and ford in the second each(). But the first one just outputs 0. Why is it doing that?

```
var cars = {
        honda : {0: "Accord", 1: "Prelude", 2: "Civic"},
        toyota: {0: "Camry", 1: "Corolla", 2: "BRZ"},
        ford: {0: "Mustang", 1: "Focus"}
}

$(cars).each(function(key, value)) {
    alert(key);
})

$.each(cars, function(key, value) {
    alert(key);
})
```

Comment: The first one is incorrect as you're trying to create a jQuery object but `cars` isn't a valid DOM element or selector, that's why it outputs `O`.

Comment: And your inner objects should really be arrays. Like `honda : ["Accord", "Prelude", "Civic"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first example outputs 0 because when you do `$(cars)`, you're wrapping your `cars` object in a jQuery object, an object with one element with index 0.

Also you should note the distinction between both "each" methods:

**[jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)** or **$.each()**:

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate
>   over both objects and arrays.

**[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**:

> Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element.

Answer (score -1):

try this, to loop through an array:

```
for (i=0; i<cars.length; i++){
    alert (cars[i]);
}
```

Comment: aren't they keys of cars the name of the cars? so wouldn't this mean that referencing element with index i return null?

Comment: right... but what i'm saying is i is an integer. in the data structure i defined above, i don't have any integer indexes
edit: sorry, i do. but they're in cars[][], not cars[]

Comment: sorry, my fault. in this case you need two loops, one inside the other one. and you'll get car models you need

Comment: OP is not working with arrays but with nested objects, objects have no length property so you're answer is not valid in this scenario